# NLopt integer steps

Tags: c++, nlopt

Is there any way to force `nlopt_optimize` to go in integer steps?
I've tried

```
double* step = new double(dbSize);
for (int i = 0; i<dbSize; i++){
    step[i] = 1;
}
nlopt_set_initial_step(optimizer, step);
```

but it doesn't seem to help much.

Algorithm used is COBYLA